# How does one successfully open a Java bug if Sun doesn't respond?

Tags: java, bug-tracking, no-response

I attempted to open a Java bug last Halloween.  I immediately got a response that my submission was accepted, and have heard nothing since.  Looking at Sun's web pages, I can't found any contact information where I can inquire.  Almost two weeks ago I made a post in the [Sun forums](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5361055) in what appears to be the most appropriate area and have no response there either.

Has anyone had success getting Sun to open a bug report after a long period of non-response?  Does anyone know who I can contact to find out the current status of my bug report?

For what it's worth, the internal review ID I was given is 1380005.

Edit, added later:

For the curious:  What is the bug?  The Java Web Start client, when downloading JAR files (or anything else), **always** adds an `If-Modified-Since` header (with a time-date equivalent of "`-1`" -- 1 second before midnight 1-1-1970 -- no matter whether the Java cache is empty or full) and **always** adds a `No-Cache` header.  Note:  This is the **client** side that supplies the `No-Cache` header!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had mixed results when submitting bug reports.  I've submitted quite a few bug reports/RFE's related to the `java.util.regex` package; they always appeared in the public database within a few weeks, and were usually resolved to my satisfaction fairly quickly.  But that's probably because the regex package is small and largely self-contained.  I've also submitted a few Swing-related bug reports, and they always took ages to go through, if they went through at all.

But I discovered two things I could do to speed things up: post questions about the bugs in the [JavaDesktop forums](http://forums.java.net/jive/category.jspa?categoryID=53), and submit patches.  It's been a year or more since I was there last, but back then there were actual Sun employees participating those forums, and if they saw merit in your bug report, they could shepherd it through the system--especially if you submitted a patch.

Comment: It's possible to submit patches even for Java 6?  For Java 7 I know it's possible.

Comment: You mean because it's open-source now?  They started accepting patches long before that happened.  All the patches I submitted were for 5 and 6.

Comment: @Alan M: Ah, I didn't know that they would accept patches before Java was opened sourced. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I did the research (took two days) to find the bug, and I submitted a patch.  It was successful.  (The patch was trivial and thus easy to verify.)  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Did you get an email telling you that your bug report will appear in the [Bug Database](http://bugs.sun.com/) soon? I filed a report once and it took about a week before appearing in the public database. There are also some caveats regarding bugs that will not be on the public database because of "[security reasons](http://developers.sun.com/resources/bugsFAQ.html)".

Comment: No such EMail yet. I just got the acknowledgment that the bug was received and would be internally reviewed.

Comment: Try replying back to the email they sent you (the one with the internal review ID number in the subject)... maybe they have a good reason for the delay.

Comment: That's all I'm trying to determine!  :)  I'll try that.

Comment: Nope, as I suspected, the EMail bounced immediately.  There is no-one listening at the address of the auto-response bot that acknowledged receipt of my bug report.

Comment: Well, I guess you could recheck the bug database and submit a fresh report.

Comment: The incident is still there in the waiting state. You may have noticed there's been a lot going on in the deployment area recently, so they are going to be a bit busy and dealing with low priority bugs is going to be a low priority.

Comment: @Tom, Thanks for the update.  At least I know it's still in the system.  Do you know of any proper way to get a bug moving that's been waiting a while?  Purchasing support?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.

They sat forever on the bug about incorrect behavior in the Java compiler & specification ("Exception cannot be thrown but it is thrown").

You might stand a chance if you can fix it yourself in the GPL'd Java 7, otherwise you're hosed.

Comment: Well, it's a trivial bug to fix.  Maybe I'll do that, although it won't help me for over a year.  (This is used in a shipping product, so we cannot ship a pre-release Java version for client desktops :)

Comment: @Joshua can you provide more details on the one they "sat forever" on?

Comment: For a pointless example: try { Thread.currentThread().stop(new IOException()); } catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println(e);}. It won't even compile. As an experiment I commented out the line in javac producing the error and it did indeed throw IOException.

Comment: @Joshua Not a bug - only unchecked or declared exception can be caught. Thread.stop(Throwable) is not *declared* as throwing IOException. The fact that it does so is just internal hackery that violates type safety of checked exceptions...but the compiler cannot be aware of that.

Comment: "only unchecked or declared exception can be caught" is in fact the bug in the spec. Comes up from time to time.